# How to include an external file with SVG defs in an HTML file

Tags: html, svg

If I have a simple HTML file, I can use `<use xlink:href="svg_defs.svg#shape1" x="10" y="10" />` to include an SVG definition of shape1 from the external file `svg_defs.svg`.

But what if my HTML file is not a simple one and it has a large number of `<use ...>` tags and what if I want the structure of my site to be flexible?

(Meaning that I may decide on a later day to move the `svg_defs.svg` file and I do not want to go and do a global search-and-replace of **all** the `svg_defs.svg` references. I want to be able to change only in one place, the file location. If this is possible.)

Is there a way to either *include* the svg_defs.svg file (like the `<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"/></script>` command), or to *define* the path somewhere (similar to the CSS mechanism: `var(--color);`) and use it only once?

Comment: Not really no. `href` is not a CSS property, so CSS variables can't help.  Global search and replace is sometimes what you just have to do.  If your defs svg is not large, you could consider inlining it in the HTML.

Comment: If your SVG code is embedded in the HTML, I guess you could refresh all the occurences with a JS loop, but it would be so CPU expensive!

Comment: @Valentin Yes, I thought of that or to have a .js file with a cons svg_defs="<defs>bla</defs>" and to do a document.getElementById("svg_canvas").innerHTML = svg_defs; but... it's not very ... (how should I phrase it?) "logical"...

Comment: In fact if you don't move this file every day, a search/replace is the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you would have to add at the first part of the code:

```
<base href=""/> <!-- Inside the "" you have to put the link that has the svg file -->
```